# Validation Rules For User Object

Tags: validation

I Need to create a validation Rules that when New User created then Manager Field should be Required. For that I have created a validation Rules below, but it is not Working.

`NOT(ISBLANK( ManagerId ))`

I am New to salesforce Please Help.

Comment: Hey Rahul, in general your questions will be easier for us to answer if you say HOW something is not working. You should try to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Usually validation rule gets triggered when the condition is true. For your case try using

`ISBLANK(ManagerID)`

No need for the `NOT`

Answer (score 2):

ISBLANK( ManagerId) this is enough. The validation rule should fire only when the Manager field is blank or null.